# MSSQL query runs slow with lot of LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I am working with mssql server 2008r2. 
I have a huge tables which contain 19 stores turnover data day by day item by item. It has some 100million rows. But with the partitioned view it is easy to run queries.

The structure of the table looks like this:

1. Store name
2. Item id
3. Date
4. Turnover
5. Selled quantity

The output report looks like this:
Item id, date, store_1.turnover, store_1.quantity, store_2.turnover, store_2.quantity....

To create this kind of report i use this query:

```
WITH cte_sell AS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM view_turnover 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '130413' and '130418' )

SELECT a.item_id,a.date,
    store_1.turnover,store_1.quantity,
    store_2.turnover,store_2.quantity,
    store_3.turnover,store_3.quantity

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item_id,date FROM cte_sell) as a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM cte_sell WHERE store='Store 1') as Store_1 ON a.item_id=store_1.item_id and a.date=store_1.date    
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM cte_sell WHERE store='Store 2') as Store_2 ON a.item_id=store_2.item_id and a.date=store_2.date    
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM cte_sell WHERE store='Store 3') as Store_3 ON a.item_id=store_3.item_id and a.date=store_3.date
```

I hope you can understand the query.

The query runs less then 10 second for 14-15 store (14 15 LEFT JOIN), which is good.
But the problem is when I select all the 19 store (19 LEFT JOIN) the query slows dramatically. It can take 2 or 3 minutes to finish.

The creation of the execution plan is much longer too:

- For 12 store only 2 seconds
- For 19 store 22 seconds

What do you think, are there any limitation of tables joining? 
I think there are some server parameter which controls the huge queries.
Has anyone any idea how to optimize the query or the server?

The worst thing, the server can freeze sometimes: I created a trace file while the query was run at 9 o'clock and at 12 o'clock. At 9 it took 2 minutes to run the query. 
At 12 I had tor restart the comupetr after 10 minutes, because I can't restart the SQL service from the Configuration manager.

I can't attach screnshots.

In the activity monitor the process is in suspended state. 
The Wait Type is: CXPACKET
The Wait Resource is: exchang....
Sorry, but I don't know much about locks.

I tried to connect from the management studio and I get this message: The connection was succesfully established with the server, but then an error occured during the login process. (Provider: TCP provider, error:0 (Translate from Hungarian): The existing connection was forced to close by the remote machine.

Comment: Does the execution plan point out any problem areas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered removing the subqueries and just using join conditions?

```
WITH cte_sell AS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM view_turnover 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '130413' and '130418' )

SELECT a.item_id,a.date,
    store_1.turnover,store_1.quantity,
    store_2.turnover,store_2.quantity,
    store_3.turnover,store_3.quantity

FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item_id,date FROM cte_sell) as a
LEFT JOIN cte_sell as Store_1 ON a.item_id=store_1.item_id and a.date=store_1.date and Store='Store 1'
LEFT JOIN cte_sell as Store_2 ON a.item_id=store_2.item_id and a.date=store_2.date and store='Store 2'
LEFT JOIN cte_sell as Store_3 ON a.item_id=store_3.item_id and a.date=store_3.date and store='Store 3'
```

Comment: Hello!
Thank you for the answer, i am testing it right now. It seems to me much better without the subquery. I also will split the turnover tables into monthly tables (now it contains a quarter of a year)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that SQL Server does not seem to optimize CTE expressions when they appear multiple times in the query.  In other words, if you look at the execution plan, the view is being executed three times -- for each mention store.

Can you have each store on a different rows?  If so, try this:

```
WITH cte_sell AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM view_turnover 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '130413' and '130418'
   )
SELECT a.item_id, a.date, store, turnover, quantity
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item_id,date FROM cte_sell) as a left join
     cte_sell cs
     on a.item_id=cs.item_id and a.date=cs.date and cs.store in ('Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3')
```

If you need one row with multiple stores, then conditional aggregation or `pivot` will solve the problem.

If you want to see the values all in one row, then use conditional aggregation on the above query:

```
WITH cte_sell AS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM view_turnover 
    WHERE date BETWEEN '130413' and '130418'
   )
SELECT a.item_id, a.date,
       max(case when store = 'Store 1' then turnover end),
       max(case when store = 'Store 1' then quantity end),
       max(case when store = 'Store 2' then turnover end),
       max(case when store = 'Store 2' then quantity end),
       max(case when store = 'Store 3' then turnover end),
       max(case when store = 'Store 3' then quantity end)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT item_id,date FROM cte_sell) as a left join
     cte_sell cs
     on a.item_id=cs.item_id and a.date=cs.date and cs.store in ('Store 1', 'Store 2', 'Store 3')
group by a.item_id, a.date
```

Comment: Hello!
Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately the users want to see in one row all the stores. I my case the pivot is not a good solution because i have some character type value (which i didn't mentioned), which cannot be summarized.